# Everyone's sid in Windows 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, acl

I am developing a .net 3.5 application that should run on both windows 8 and 7.

As part of the application I am creating a new folder under C:\ProgramData.

After creating the folder I set the following ACL - Allow everyone to read and write.

```
 var directorySecurity = directoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
 var worldSecurityIdentifier = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);     
 directorySecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(worldSecurityIdentifier, FileSystemRights.Read, AccessControlType.Allow));
 directorySecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(worldSecurityIdentifier, FileSystemRights.Write, AccessControlType.Allow));
```

On Windows 8 I encounter the following behavior:  if I copy a file to that directory, when I look at the security tab in the file's properties, this is what I see.

[image: Security tab of a file that was copied into the directory]

I don't understand who is this user and how it was created. and also where is the ACL that I defined for everyone?

It seems that this unknown SID got the ACLs that I had set for Everyone.

I suspected that maybe this is because I am developing on .net 3.5 instead of 4, but when I changed the target framework to 4 it didn't help.

When I check in debug what is the worldSecurityIdentifier, this is what I get

[image]

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: Looks like a Logon Session SID. `S-1-1-0` is World/Everybody.

Comment: I know. when I debug my program I can see that the wourldSecurityIdentifier is s-1-1-0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
directorySecurity.AddAccessRule(
   new FileSystemAccessRule(
       worldSecurityIdentifier,
       FileSystemRights.Read | FileSystemRights.Write,
       InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
       PropagationFlags.None,
       AccessControlType.Allow));
```

This will set the ACE so it is Inherited by child objects.

Comment: The ACE in your original code was set to InheritanceFlags.None, so it would not be passed on to newly created files in the directory.   This sets the flag so new files and directories will inherit the ACE.

Comment: and what is this unknown SID?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I would guess it is an ACE that is being inherited from further up in the directory structure, and that is for an account that has been deleted, which is why it isn't resolved.  You should look at the permissions of the parent directories and see if the SID shows up there, and if so remove it.

Comment: And why it is getting the exact same ACL as the one I gave to "everyone"? (if I give to everyone only read permission this user will have only read permissions.)

Comment: Did you check the directory and all directories further up in the tree and remove it from wherever you found it.  It is possible it is there already since you are editing, not replacing the ACL.  Clean it up using Explorer, both from this directory and any parent directories,  and then see if it comes back when you run your program.  There is nothing in the code you posted that should be creating it.

Comment: I did, but it doesn't appear anywhere up the tree. further more, I removed all the access control rules from the folder, and it didn't help.